# SQLYOG - SQL - Merging two columns into 1 column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two columns displaying the same type of information but not necessarily the same data. Although some of the data overlaps each column may/may not contain information that will also include `NULL` values. Like so:

```
Company ID | Company Name | Company ID | Company Name
-----------+--------------+------------+-------------
1          | A            | 1          | A
2          | B            | NULL       | NULL
NULL       | NULL         | 3          | C
```

I am trying to merge columns 1 and 2 to columns 3 and 4, respectively, so that I have two columns that look like this:

```
Company ID | Company Name
-----------+-------------
1          | A 
2          | B   
3          | C
```

Looking at similar stackoverflow questions, I have doubt this may be done easily. Is this possible? Please, let me know!

Anything helps.

Comment: For the case 
1) where column 1 and 2 are empty you can just check for that fact and update the columns with the values from 3 and 4. 
Case 2) where 3 and 4 are empty: in reverse. 
For the last case 3) data in 1,2,3 and 4 I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: Do columns 1 and 3 and 2 and 4 have the same name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>As you don't seem to be around to answer questions for clarification right now, let's go ahead.</sup>
It seems, you do actually have the four columns in question in a single table - but than, there should be no duplicate column names. Once they are unique, the following should work:

```
UPDATE SomeTable
  SET company_ID_1 = IFNULL(company_ID_1, company_ID_2)
  , company_Name_1 = IFNULL(company_Name_1, company_Name_2)
WHERE
  company_ID_1 IS NULL
  OR
  company_Name_1 IS NULL
;
```

If the presented is actually the output of a join, you could replace the same by:

```
SELECT
  IFNULL(SomeTable1.company_ID, SomeTable2.company_ID) company_ID
  , IFNULL(SomeTable1.company_Name, SomeTable2.company_Name) company_Name
FROM SomeTable1
LEFT JOIN SomeTable2
  ON SomeTable1.company_ID = SomeTable2.company_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT
  IFNULL(SomeTable1.company_ID, SomeTable2.company_ID) company_ID
  , IFNULL(SomeTable1.company_Name, SomeTable2.company_Name) company_Name
FROM SomeTable1
RIGHT JOIN SomeTable2
  ON SomeTable1.company_ID = SomeTable2.company_ID
WHERE SomeTable1.company_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY company_ID
;
```

See it in action: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3ec99/1)

Please comment, if and as this requires adjustment / further detail.

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer. It seems like the information I provided might have been a little ambiguous.

Comment: I am attempting to create a table that possess' two types of information 1. for company A and 2. for company B. The reason why there are 4 columns is because the first set of company id and company name is for company A and the second set is for company B.

In addition, after each set, you have a date column (not visible) of when the company first started to become a customer for company A and then company B, respectively. There are instances when I have null values for company A because the client is  only a client of company B. 

You're answer only outputs information for company A customers

Comment: @Aurora Thanks for the update. Unfortunately still not getting the full picture, though, it seems: If the input table in your problem description is, what you actually need - why do you want to convert it into something not useful to you? --  Would you mind updating your problem statement - in particular input data and expect result?

Comment: @Aurora At this time, the suggested solution takes the presented input and produces the expected output - as detailed in your request. If you would like to see more columns to be taken care of, please, add them to both your input, and expected output.

Comment: Hey Abecee you are correct, thank you for your help it was extremely useful!